# How to plot 2D data (image) with x and y coordinates

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I would like to plot a 2D spectrum where the x coordinate is the spectral dimension (wavelength) and the y coordinate is the spatial dimension (in arcseconds of the sky) using pyqtgraph.

I've been able to do this using an ImageItem() but I cannot seem to figure out how to display the x and y axes in the right coordinates.
I don't want to just change the labels or the ticks but indeed the coordinates of the plot because I later need to perform operations using these values (wavelength and arcsecs).

Here is a minimal working example:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np


# The fake data
wvlg = np.linspace(300, 600, 5000)
arcsec = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
flux = np.ones((wvlg.shape[0], arcsec.shape[0])) * np.exp(-(arcsec)**2/0.1)
flux += np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=(wvlg.shape[0], arcsec.shape[0]))

# The plotting
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
ax2D = win.addPlot(title='2D spectrum', row=0, col=0)
img = pg.ImageItem()
img.setImage(flux)
ax2D.addItem(img)
# Some line converting the x and y values to wvlg and arcsec
```

This gives an image where the x and y axis show the index value, whereas I would like to show the corresponding wavelength and arcsec values.

[image: The 2D spectrum plotted but without the coordinates in the x and y axes]

Is there an easy way to do this that I just grossly overlooked in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setRect` method of the `ImageItem` class to set the extent of the data.  See my example below.

Note that I moved the image by half a pixel so that the pixel centers match the exact coordinates. Otherwise the coordinates would align with one of the pixel's corner points.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    
    # The fake data
    wvlg = np.linspace(300, 600, 5000)
    arcsec = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
    flux = np.ones((wvlg.shape[0], arcsec.shape[0])) * np.exp(-(arcsec)**2/0.1)
    flux += np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=(wvlg.shape[0], arcsec.shape[0]))

    # The plotting
    win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
    ax2D = win.addPlot(title='2D spectrum', row=0, col=0)
    img = pg.ImageItem()
    img.setImage(flux)
    ax2D.addItem(img)
    
    print(flux.shape)

    # Move the image by half a pixel so that the center of the pixels are
    # located at the coordinate values
    dx = wvlg[1]-wvlg[0]
    dy = arcsec[1]-arcsec[0]
    print("pixel size x: {}, pixel size y: {}".format(dx, dy))
    
    rect = QtCore.QRectF(wvlg[0] - dx/2, arcsec[0] - dy/2, 
                         wvlg[-1] - wvlg[0], arcsec[-1] - arcsec[0])
    print(rect)
    img.setRect(rect)

    ax2D.setLabels(left='arcsec', bottom='wvlg')
    
    win.show()
    win.raise_()
    app.exec_()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```